# Payment disabled for this user

Tags: facebook-ads-api

Hi can someone help me figure out what's the problem on this one. I'm trying to create an ad on facebook but it doesn't allow me by saying "Payment is disabled for this user". Then on the meta version, this shows up:

"Sorry, something unexpected happened. Try again. (Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'act_10150115732027885' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api (#100.33))"

Thank you in advance.

I tried changing my credit card details and all but no luck